# Limit of integral over set measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

If $A\subset[0,2\pi]$ is measurable, prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A \cos (nx)\ dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_A \sin(nx) \ dx=0$$

Please, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This an application of the Riemann Lebesgue Lemma to the indicator funciton $1_A(x)$. You can however prove it from scratch. Prove the result holds true for $A$ being an interval, then a union of disjoint intervals. Then use the fact that any measurable set can be approximated by open/closed sets from outside/inside.

Comment: I do not have the theorem Riemann Lebesgue; :(

Comment: @user126033: then you can prove this version of it from scratch as outlined above. The result is trivial for intervals by fundamental theorem of calculus.