# Use squeeze theorem to integrate over a measurable set $A \subset [-\pi, \pi]$?

Tags: calculus, limits, measure-theory, definite-integrals, characteristic-functions

In trying to prove that

$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_A \cos(kt)dt=0$$

where $A \subset [-\pi, \pi]$ is a measurable set, what is wrong with the following?

1. $$0 = \int_B 0 \times \cos(kt)dt \le \int_B 1_A \times \cos(kt)dt \le \int_B 1 \times \cos(kt)dt = \frac{\sin(\pi k)-\sin(-\pi k)}{k}$$
2. There is some $B$ for which $(1)$ is true.
3. Then squeeze theorem as $k \to \infty$

Related:

[Limit of integral over set measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009579/limit-of-integral-over-set-measurable)

[Can/cannot one integrate over a measurable set $A \subset [-\pi, \pi]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698903/can-cannot-one-integrate-over-a-measurable-set-a-subset-pi-pi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with your reasoning is that $\cos(kt)$ may be negative, so it is not true that multiplying by it preserves inequalities, as you implicitly assumed. The fact that in the end you found $0 \le ... \le 2 \sin(k\pi)/k$ and that this last value may be negative should have phased you a little...

Comment: Not really. Seems like a standard trick in learning first class of advanced probability theory where everything there is positive. Been 5 years since I've done real analysis/measure theory. Thanks Najib Idrissi! ^-^